# Jquery addclass not working to apply a "fadeoutdown" effect to a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For some reason the "fadeOutdown" effect (from this [website](http://daneden.me/animate)) doesn't work when I click on .article-close. Would you know why? JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yg3Ue/ Thanks

JS:

```
$(".article-close").click(function() {
  $("#article").addClass("animated fadeOutDown");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="article" class="animated fadeInLeftBig">
<div class="article-close"></div>
    <h1>Neque porro quisquam es</h1>
    <p>Lorem ips um dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sit amet diam nisl. Aliquam quis est eu elit facilisis aliquam. Pellentesque porta nunc diam</p>
    <h2>Sub-title</h2><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
 Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>    <a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_b.jpg" title="Caption. Can be aligned it to any side.">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8589392310_7b6127e243_s.jpg" width="75" height="75">
</a><h2>Sub-title</h2><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
<h2>Sub-title</h2><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
<h2>Sub-title</h2><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
    <p><strong>LOREM IPSUM</strong></p>
          <h3>Tel. +123 456.789 - E-mail: contact@kjhhklh.com</h3>
    <p><a href="index.html">Lorem ipsum ›</a></p>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: You're not using jQuery..http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yg3Ue/1/

Comment: Thanks. Strange, now it works on your fiddle but not offline. I put this btw my head tags. Am I missing something? <script>
$(".article-close").click(function() {
  $("#article").addClass("animated fadeOutDown");
});
</script>

Comment: you need to include jQuery http://jquery.com/download/ include the JS library in your file `<head>` section.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but unfortunately it's no working so I guess the issue must be somewhere else (see link http://goo.gl/Wpyrz ) Tks for your help

Comment: Try this `$(document).on('click', '.article-close', function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code, using `.on`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.article-close', function() {
 $('#article').addClass('class1 class2');
});
```